# Lost some string variables in struct while transform it into byte array

Tags: c#, windows

I have big struct which I need to send through tcp

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct FullInfo
{
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string id_name;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string type;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string type_id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2048)]
        public string protocol;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2048)]
        public string connection;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2048)]
        public string name;
        ......
}
```

Then I transform it into byte array by

```
public byte[] WriteStruct<T>(T structure)
{
       int rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);
       IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
       Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, buffer, false);
       byte[] rawdata = new byte[rawsize];
       Marshal.Copy(buffer, rawdata, 0, rawsize);
       Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
       return rawdata;
}
```

After send I transform it back to struct by

```
public T ReadStruct0<T>(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
{
       byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[count];
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            tempBuffer[i] = buffer[index + i];
       }
       GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(tempBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
       T temp = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
       handle.Free();
       return temp;
}
```

And most of values have 0 length but server struct has them.

Comment: The code you posted works so the error must be elsewhere. (Obviously you can test your code by checking that ReadStruct(WriteStruct(x)) == x)

Comment: I can't receive connection and name they are equals " " on client. I couldn't check it like that ReadStruct(WriteStruct(x)) == x) becouse I send from server and receive in client

Comment: Yes, but you can check the code you posted here in a unit test or some other coded test, and you will see that it works fine. Therefore, the error must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Marshalling~  often require types to be blittable, i.e. it should be possible to just copy the memory for the values. Strings are reference types and therefore not blittable. There are probably ways to make marshalling work, but I have no idea how to do it.</s>

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, marshalling of string is probably not the issue. But using using more common serialization methods is probably still relevant. I would also recommend writing tests so you can test the serialization separate from the transportation.

A more typical .Net way would be to use a [BinaryWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binarywriter?view=netcore-3.1)/[BinaryReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader?view=netcore-3.1) to write down each value to a `MemoryStream`. Or use a propper serialization library to do it. I can recommend [protobuf.net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net), this requires adding attributes to your types, but you are doing that anyway. In either case, convert the memorystream to a `byte[]` and send it over the network. In my experience a good serialization library will be easier, faster, produce less data, and is much easier to manage backwards and forwards compatibility compared to a home grown solution.

Comment: The marshaller takes care of transferring the strings for you, so it should work (if strings couldn't be marshalled, we'd have a lot of problems with P/Invoke!). But I agree that this requires a serialisation solution rather than a marshalling solution.

Comment: @Matthew Watson, thanks for the information. I have rarely used marshalling, it just seemed like the wrong approach to the problem.